# TensorFlow InvalidArgumentError when reading record for training on own image set

Tags: python, tensorflow

i'am trying to train my own images (682x1024x3= 2095104 Pixels)  with TensorFlow. Therefore i combined several published scripts to 1) create a .tfrcords file using the TFRecord writer 2) to read this record and 3) to train them.
To read the images i took the function *read_images*() from here: https://github.com/HamedMP/ImageFlow/blob/master/ImageFlow.py
and change it into these code

```
def read_images(path_queue, is_directory=True):
    images = []
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    jpeg_files = path_queue
    if len(jpeg_files) > 0:
       jpeg_file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(jpeg_files)
       jkey, jvalue = reader.read(jpeg_file_queue)
       j_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(jvalue)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Start populating the filename queue.
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        if len(jpeg_files) > 0:
           for i in range(len(jpeg_files)):
           jpeg = j_img.eval()
           images.append(jpeg)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
return np.asarray(images)
```

the result of *read_images*() i pass  with list of labels and filename to the *convert_to*() function published here: https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py

my changes in script where

```
rows = images[0].shape[0]
cols = images[0].shape[1]
depth = images[0].shape[2]
```

and the for loop i am cutting the labelId out of the string

```
for index in range(num_examples):
    print ('pics written: %d '%index)
    image_raw = images[index].tostring()
    print ('len: %d'%len(image_raw))
    label = labels[index]
    lbl = int(label[(len(label)-5):len(label)])
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'height': _int64_feature(rows),
        'width': _int64_feature(cols),
        'depth': _int64_feature(depth),
        'label': _int64_feature(lbl),
        'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_raw)}))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

i did no change inside the *_int64_feature*() an *_bytes_feature*()
Debuger say at that poin that my values of variables are:

- rows=682  cols=1024  depth=3
  and *len(image_raw)* gives me 2095104 this equal to pixels

so thats the way i write the record.
to read the record i'am using this script:

/master/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/mnist.py

and this one:

/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py
(sry just 2 links allowed)

i changed the vlaue 1000 into capacity=10+ 3 * batchsize and min_after_deque=10 inside *inputs*() function (second last line):

```
images, sparse_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [image, label], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=2,
    capacity=1000 + 3 * batch_size,
    # Ensures a minimum amount of shuffling of examples.
    min_after_dequeue=1000)
```

Now i don't (see)have any issue one creating a TFRecord but when i run the whole script i'am getting the foliwing error:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1027] 0x7fb89bae8860 Compute status: Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 0. Expected [2095104], got [2101248]
 [[Node: input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue_enqueue = QueueEnqueue[Tcomponents=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, input/sub, input/Cast_1)]]
```

which say i Expected **[2095104]=682x1024x3**, got **[2101248]=684x1024x3**

so i don't have no idea where thes 2 extra Pixels come from. can somebody help?

the error occures in the *inputs*() function on line (117 published code)

```
images, sparse_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [image, label], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=2,
    capacity=10 + 3 * batch_size,
    # Ensures a minimum amount of shuffling of examples.
    min_after_dequeue=10)
```

Comment: Perhaps the image processing is rounding up the size to a multiple of 4? Have you tried putting different size images in, to see if there is a pattern to the size change?

Comment: I resized my images into size 341x227x3 created a record. read the record brings similar error:                                                                                 Shape mismatch in tuple component 0. Expected [232221], got [233244]
Currently i don't see a patter but difference is 1023

Comment: That is 3 pixels added - the new size is 344, again a multiple of 4. Can you crop/resize to a multiple of 4 in both x and y?

Comment: @barny Not currently. I tried to do it with tensorflow 'j_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(jvalue,3,4)' but that didn't work. I found some solutions with PIL where images are resized in both x and y but don't try them. i will do these this week.

Comment: @barny Hi barny it works. solution:1.) resize image into 1024x768 2.) resize it again into IMAGE_HIGHT = 192 IMAGE_WIDTH = 256.(how you see it's just divided by 4.) the error didn't occure. but now I have some other issues wich worth a own question. thx a lot barny. Used this code snippet.                                                                                             im = Image.open(source_folders[i]).resize((1024,768))
im = im.resize((256,192),Image.ANTIALIAS)

Comment: You should make your comment an answer as people often don't look at comments for an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Moving Alexander's comment-answer to a real answer:

1.) resize image into 1024x768

2.) resize it again into IMAGE_HIGHT = 192 IMAGE_WIDTH = 256. (how you see it's just divided by 4.)

OP used this code snippet.

```
im = Image.open(source_folders[i]).resize((1024,768)) 
im = im.resize((256,192),Image.ANTIALIAS)
```